# MS Bot Framework stuck sending messages in an infinite loop

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

My bot that uses MS Bot Framework is stuck sending messages to the user in an infinite loop, both on the `facebook` and `emulator` channels.

My bot has a "root" `IDialog`, kind of like a menu, that calls a few other `IDialog`s depending on the user's selection. The child dialogs are called in this way:

```
        ...
        else if (response.Text == MainOptions[2])
        {
            await context.Forward(new InfoCounterDialog(), ChildDialogComplete, 
                                  response, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        ...
```

- `response` is an `IMessageActivity` sent by user;
- `ChildDialogComplete` is a method that builds the main menu again and ends with these lines:

.

```
await context.PostAsync(restartPrompt);
context.Wait(MainScreenSelectionReceived);
```

All dialogs work fine except this one very short dialog, which causes an infinite loop - the bot keeps sending this message again and again until I stop the web app.

```
namespace XXXX
{
[Serializable]
public class InfoCounterDialog : IDialog
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        var hourNow = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        var openNow = "";
        if (hourNow >= 7)
        {
            openNow = "It is open now and will close at midnight.";
        }
        else
        {
            openNow = "It is closed now and will open at 7:00";
        }
        var card = HeroCardUtils.CardWithImageAndMiscButtons(
            "Our information counter can help!",
            "It's located in Shop 081, Level 3 in Building 2. " + openNow,
            "http://www.[image URL here].jpg",
            new[] { "More Details" },
            new[] { ActionTypes.OpenUrl },
            new[] { "[webpage URL here]" }
            );
        await BotUtils.SendCardToChat(context, card);
        context.Done(this);
    }
}
```

}

If you're wondering what `SendCardToChat` does:

```
    public async static Task SendCardToChat(IDialogContext context, HeroCard card)
    {
        var activity = context.MakeMessage();
        activity.Attachments = HeroCardUtils.CardToAttachments(card);
        await context.PostAsync(activity);
    }
```

To recap:

- I'm launching a dialog from another dialog using `context.Forward()`
- The dialog is supposed to show a message to the user and immediately terminate without extra input from user
- Instead, it keeps sending the *"Our information counter can help!"* message infinitely.

My best guess is that the child dialog somehow returns the user's initial message to the conversation, which triggers the same dialog again and again. But this shouldn't happen, the child `IDialog` shouldn't send anything to the conversation except the `HeroCard` I created.

Or maybe I'm looking in a wrong direction and Bot Framework just doesn't support `IDialog`s that do something and immediately terminate without a `context.Wait()`?

Comment: Have u tried moving the logic from the StartAsync to a MessageReceivedAsync type method? You are doing context.Forward so you don't need to put the logic in StartAsync...

Comment: @EzequielJadib so you mean the `StartAsync()` should do nothing? If it needs to call another method, I assume you have to do `context.Wait()` and that means waiting for one more input from the user, which I want to avoid and show the message immediately.

Comment: You need to do context.Wait() but if you are doing context.Forward you won't be waiting for user input, the message will pass through. Let me know and I will post the answer

Answer (score 1):

I found that there isn't much documentation on context.Done(R value) but its really important in controlling the flow of the dialog.

I'm guessing that context.Done(this) calls your Dialog again?  have you tried

```
context.Done(true);
```

I'm finding it frustrating that there isn't a context.Done() method (no parameter) to tell the dialog that your finished.

Further to this, i've found that in [this Microsoft Example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs/Dialogs/HotelsDialog.cs) they use

```
// within a HotelsDialog.cs
context.Done<object>(null);
```

This is possible because they call the dialog from a [root dialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs/Dialogs/RootDialog.cs)

```
// within RootDialog.cs
context.Call(new HotelsDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
```

Comment: I've solved the problem in some other way, although I don't remember how. I keep using context.Done(this) successfully in other projects. I assume that this is the IDialog object that we're terminating.

Comment: Further to this, i've started using context.Done<object>(null); similar to the finally statement in this ms example class https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs/Dialogs/HotelsDialog.cs